# Discord.py bot not able to send embed messages?

Tags: discord.py, discord-interactions

Trying to implement embedded messages for my discord bot using interactions. The following is the code with the error message under it.

```
import interactions
import discord

bot = interactions.Client(token="<REDACTED>")

@bot.command(
    name="test",
    description="Tests"
)
async def test(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    embed = interactions.Embed(
        title="testing",
        description="test purposes"
    )
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Error Message:

```
payload = await super().send(content, **kwargs)

TypeError: _Context.send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'embed'
```

Comment: Which documentation states that it should take that kwarg?

Comment: try `await ctx.channel.send(embed = embed)` and let me know if that works

Comment: @JyotirmayKumarJha gives `AttributeError: type object 'MISSING' has no attribute 'send'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[interactions.py documentation](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=embed#ctx-send-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-embed-why) said `This is quite simple: The argument embed got deprecated by Discord. The new naming is embeds.`

Changed embed into embeds and it works now.

```
@bot.command(
    name="test",
    description="Tests"
)
async def test(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    embeds = interactions.Embed(
        title="testing",
        description="test purposes"
    )
    await ctx.send(embeds = embeds)
```